# Meteor collection issues

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

I have a strange issue when using the npm module Graph: https://github.com/mhelvens/graph.js

When I load this module in a file on the server, my collections are no longer available on the client.

When I do:

```
Albums.find().fetch()
```

I get the collection on the client. But whenever I import the Graph library the call above returns an empty array `[]`.

This is how I import the module:

```
var Graph = require('graph.js/dist/graph.full.js');
```

I can access the collection server side, but not from the client, even though I could before the line of code above.